# UILabel with dynamic height into UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an app which required to display `UILabel` into `UITableviewCell`. I also need to resize `UILabel` as per text size.
I am using following code for get `contentsize` of text size.

```
CGRect rect = [as boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(220.0, 2000.0) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil];
```

For update frame of `UILabel` I use following code.

```
 rect.origin.x = cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.x;
 rect.origin.y = cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.y;
 rect.size.width = cell.lblDescription.frame.size.width;

 [cell.lblDescription setFrame:rect];
```

It set wrong frame.
Please find attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr_cart objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12];
    CGSize size = [(text ? text : @"") sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    UILabel *lbl_desc=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl_desc.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl_desc.frame=CGRectMake(70,18, size.width, size.height);
    lbl_desc.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl_desc.text = (text ? text : @"");
    lbl_desc.font = font;
    lbl_desc.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lbl_desc.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_desc];
    [lbl_desc release];
```

Comment: As I am using already added UILabel into Xib, it is not working. So, use above code and add new UILabel into cellforRowAtIndexpath() method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the height of the label in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` UITableViewDelegate Method.

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(your_label_width, FLT_MAX);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [label_text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"your_font" size:your_font_size] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

then set the cell height as `expectedLabelSize.height`.

also do the same thing in your custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
[self setDynamicHeightOfLabel:lblName withLblWidth:97 andFontSize:13];
```

In above method you just need to pass your `UILabel` name with specific **width and fontSize** of label.

```
-(void) setDynamicHeightOfLabel:(UILabel *) myLabel withLblWidth:(CGFloat) width andFontSize:(int) fontSize
{
    CGSize myLabelSize = CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize expecteingmyLabelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:myLabelSize lineBreakMode:myLabel.lineBreakMode];
    CGRect lblFrame = myLabel.frame;
    lblFrame.size.height = expecteingmyLabelSize.height;
    myLabel.frame = lblFrame;
    int addressLine = myLabel.frame.size.height/fontSize;
    myLabel.numberOfLines = addressLine;
}
```

Using above code you can set dynamic height of `UILabel`.